# Passport that had my Schengen vignette in it was stolen in the UK

Tags: schengen-visas, spain

I returned from Spain this week. However on arrival my handbag was stolen. The bag had my passport and the Schengen vignette. I have applied for re-issuance for my Indian passport with the High Commission of India.

However when it comes to getting my Schengen visa back, I’m totally clueless on the process. I called BLS Manchester, which handles the visa applications for the Spanish Consulate. They have no answer to this situation. And the number provided on Google and the website by the Spanish Consulate doesn’t work. Can someone guide me what to do now? I have trips planned and a lot of money will be lost.

Comment: It partially does. @DavidRecallsMonica … however, I did ring the consulate I was hoping to get a new visa from but they mentioned till the time I’ve an active Schengen visa on my passport I can’t re-apply. Yesterday the last resort they suggest me was to somehow get in touch with Spanish consulate who granted me the visa to check the process and no one else can revoke my existing visa.